# How can I find a lift for this circle homeomorphism?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

> Let me consider the circle homeomorphism $T:\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}$s.t. $T(x)=x+\frac{1}{2}$ if $x\in [0, 1/2]$ and $T(x)=x-\frac{1}{2} $ if $x\in [1/2,1]$.

Now I want to find a lift $F:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$. This means $F$ needs to be continuous and $\pi(F(x))=T(\pi(x))$ for all $x\in \Bbb{R}$ where $\pi:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}; x\mapsto x+\Bbb {Z}$.

My idea was somehow to glue this two functions together. But the problem is that I don't see how to guarantee that $\pi(F(x))=T(\pi(x))$ holds. I thought about defining $F(x)=x+\frac{1}{2}$ if $0\leq x~ \operatorname{mod}~ 1< 1/2$ and $F(x)=x- \frac{1}{2} $ if $1/2\leq ~ \operatorname{mod}~ 1 \leq 1$ . Equivalently I can say

$$F (x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
x+\frac{1}{2} & x \in [k, k+1/2), \forall k\in \Bbb{Z} \\
x- \frac{1}{2}& \, x\in [k+1/2, k+1], \forall k\in \Bbb{Z} \\
\end{array}
\right. $$

But I think I messed up with continuity of $F$.

Can someone tell me if it works and if not correct my idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: $T(0) \ne T(1) \mod 1$, so that's not a circle homeomorphism.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC i edited my question, I think now it should be a circle homeomorphism. Can you help me now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply take $F(x) = x + \frac 1 2$. Then we have $F(x) - F(y) =  x - y$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb R$. Writing $\pi(x) = [x] = x + \mathbb Z$, we therefore see that if $[x] = [y]$, then $[F(x)] = [F(y)]$. This means that $F$ induces a unique $F^* : \mathbb R/ \mathbb Z \to \mathbb R/ \mathbb Z$ such that $\pi \circ F = F^* \circ \pi$. Explicitly, $F^*([x]) = [F(x)] = [x + \frac 1 2]$.

It remains to show that $F^* = T$. Since each $\xi \in \mathbb R/ \mathbb Z$ can be written as $\xi = [x]$ with $x \in [0,1]$, it therefore suffices to consider the following two cases:

1. $x \in [0, \frac 1 2]$. Then
   $$F^*([x]) = [x + \frac 1 2] = T([x]).$$
2. $x \in [\frac 1 2, 1]$. Then
   $$F^*([x]) = [x + \frac 1 2] = [x + \frac 1 2 - 1 ] = [x - \frac 1 2] = T([x]).$$

Comment: Why do you only take $[0,1/2],[1/2,1]$? Shouldn‘t $F$ be a function on $\Bbb{R}$? So I don‘t get how to do it with the domain or is the domain true as I wrote it above with mod?

Comment: @user123234 See my update.

Comment: So my approach above which I also wrote in the comment from the second answer will not work? Or why do you work with $F*$

Comment: @user123234 Your approach does not work because your $F$ is not continuous at the points $x = k + 1/2$. I showed that $F$ lifts the induced $F^*$ (which is trivial by construction) and then that $F^* = T$.

Comment: Sorry I dont get why my is not continuous, and what do you mean by $F$ lifts $F*$, does this mean F is the lift of F*? But i mean we want to construct the lift F?

Comment: @user123234 $F(k+1/2) = k$, but if $x \to k+1/2$ from the left, then $F(x) \to k+1$.  Saying that $F$ lifts $F^*$ means indeed that $F$ is a lift of $F^*$. This is due to the construction which gives $\pi \circ F = F^* \circ \pi$. I constructed a map $F$ which is a lift of $T = F^*$ and this is what we have to do.

Comment: Aha I see the point with the lift. But with the continuity. Are you now speaking abaut the F in my original question or the F, I wrote in the comment to the answer of Rob? Because the F in the comment should be continuous no?

Comment: @user123234 I meant the $F$ is your question. The $F$ in your comment is precisely my $F$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: in $\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}$, you are working modulo $1$, just as in $\Bbb{Z}_2$ (a.k.a., $\Bbb{Z}/\Bbb{2Z}$) you work modulo $2$. In modulo $2$ arithmetic, you have $-1 \simeq 1$, because $1 - (-1) = 2 \simeq 0$, and similarly, in modulo $1$ arithmetic you have $-\frac{1}2 \simeq \frac{1}{2}$. So you can forget all those minus signs: your function $T$ is just adding $\frac{1}{2}$ modulo $1$.

Comment: Ah I see but then with the domain of $F$ is it true when I say $F(x)=x+\frac{1}{2}$ if $0\leq x~ \operatorname{mod}~ 1< 1/2$ and $F(x)=x+ \frac{1}{2} $ if $1/2\leq ~ \operatorname{mod}~ 1 \leq 1$?

Comment: You don't need a case split in the definition of $F$, you can just take $F$ to be the function that adds $1/2$: $F(x) = x + 1/2$. Continuity is now clear and you just need to convince yourself that $\pi(F(x)) = T(\pi(x))$.